# uitextview text displaying on ios 7 but not on ios 6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i have added multiple uitextfields programatically on uiscrollview its working fine and displaying text in ios 7 . but i am facing problem on ios 6 it does not display text its just display a large empty area with black background on uiscrollview this is the code

```
// set array values to label
-(void)addTextViews:(NSArray *)qualArray
{
   //adding qualification label
   UILabel *qualLbl;
   if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
   {
        qualLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, imgVw.bounds.size.height+20, 100, 20)];
        [qualLbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
   }
   else
         qualLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, imgVw.bounds.size.height+20, 150, 20)];
     [qualLbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0]];
   }

    [qualLbl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:226.0f/255.0f green:73.0f/255.0f blue:20.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
    [qualLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [qualLbl setText:@"Qualification"];
    [self.srcVw addSubview:qualLbl];
    // adding text views
   NSLog(@"img view height %f",imgVw.bounds.size.height);
   height = imgVw.bounds.size.height + 55;

    for (int i = 0; i < qualArray.count ; i++) {
        UITextView *txtVw ;
        UILabel *symbolLabel;
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            txtVw =[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, height, self.srcVw.bounds.size.width-50, 0)];
            [txtVw setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];

            symbolLabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, height, 25, 25)];
            [symbolLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
        }
        else
        {
            txtVw =[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, height, self.srcVw.bounds.size.width-50, 0)];
            [txtVw setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]];

            symbolLabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, height, 25, 25)];
            [symbolLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
        }

        [txtVw setScrollEnabled:NO];
        [txtVw setEditable:NO];
        [txtVw  setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,[qualArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [txtVw sizeToFit];
        [txtVw setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [txtVw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [self.srcVw addSubview:txtVw];
        //  [txtVw setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        //setting symbol label properties
        [symbolLabel  setText:@">"];
        [symbolLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [symbolLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:226.0f/255.0f green:73.0f/255.0f blue:20.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
        [self.srcVw addSubview:symbolLabel];
        height = height + txtVw.frame.size.height;
    }
}
```

its code working perfect in ios 7 but i don't know what is problen when i run it on ios 6

Comment: I am wondering, since your qualArray can contains more than one elements, why are you adding txtVw and symbolLabel at same position on every loop?

Comment: I suspect problem appeared to be [txtVw setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] as by default textview's background is white and you are rendering text with white color.

Comment: i have set [txtVw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; and also i told you its working perfectly on ios 7 simulator

Answer (score 2):

you have set height of uitextview to Zero(0)

```
txtVw =[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, height, self.srcVw.bounds.size.width-50, 0)];
```

just change it to 30

```
txtVw =[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, height, self.srcVw.bounds.size.width-50, 30)];
```

because in iOS 7 it takes default size but in iOS 6 it not taking default value.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to change the deltas in the interface builder if not you are not using autolayout.[image: I added 10 px to the textfield's height]